# MySQL - Find number in string of comma-separated numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, query-string

I have a table of user data. A user is able to 'block' another user, denying them access to any of their posts (think "a social media site").

If '`blockeduserids`' is the name of the comma separated list, and the IDs contained within it are integers, how do I select users which do not block the viewing user?

Non-working example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE [the blocked user's ID] NOT IN blockeduserids;
```

Comment: Note that you should not be storing this as a comma-separated list.  That's a very problematic design.  A new table with just two columns, blocked_user_id and blocking_user_id, with both columns as the primary key and a secondary index on whichever column isn't leftmost in the PK, would be far more correct and efficient.  What you're doing now will absolutely collapse under load as you scale up, because it requires scanning every row looking for a match. (Also you could add a date column for the blocking, which might be handy, later).  Then use a left join or `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to query.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm changing this approach at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('blockedid', blockeduserids) = 0;
```

But, in general, it is not desirable to persist comma separated strings in your database tables.  A better design would be to have each blocked user id in a separate table.  If you had such a separate table, you could write:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blockeduserstable b WHERE u.user_id = b.user_id);
```

This would likely greatly outperform your current approach.

Comment: Thanks! I tried FIND_IN_SET() (and still am trying) but I keep getting no data returned. I agree I didn't immediately approach this in an ideal fashion though, will definitely take onboard creating a relationship between the tables, and I'm confident that second suggestion would work.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` has its own peculiarities.  It won't work unless the CSV string against which you are searching has no spaces (or, if there are spaces, then I think your search string would also have to match this).